# Display a person column in search result webpart SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, search, search-results, display-template

I want to add a person column with person's name and image in search result webpart. I create a item display template and add this property "Team Member" to this custom template.

[image]

But the results cannot display name with person's image. It always show

```
name@domain.com | NAME | 693A30232E777C736172657465635C6A706D61737369636F74 i:0#.w|DOMAIN\NAME
```

How could I change this to person's name and image ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, a litte stupid but it works
I add javascript to get user's photo from mysite

```
<div id="UserOWSUSER" class="ms-peopleux-userImgDiv">Nom : _#= ctx.CurrentItem.UserOWSUSER=#_</div>
            <!--#_  var UserData = ctx.CurrentItem.UserOWSUSER;
                    var UserNumber = UserData.indexOf("@");
                    var ResName = UserData.substr(0,UserNumber);
                    var UserPhotoUrl = "http://mysite.domain:80/User Photos/Images of profil/"+ResName+"_MThumb.jpg"; _#-->
        <div><img id="PIC" style="clip: rect(0px, 72px, 72px, 0px); min-height: 72px; min-width: 72px; max-width: 72px;" src="_#= UserPhotoUrl =#_"></div>
```

Comment: You should handle the case that the person does not have a picture.

Comment: @MaxMelcher yes, I add JavaScript to check if the picture exist. If the person does not have a picture, it displays image blank by default. (the image with grey background colour)